# What would be the point of sending users over to LinkedIn?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, posting

I have noticed a pattern that is a concern for me and I have reported several of these patterns.

When looking at jobs I have noticed a pattern that concerns me for jobs being posted in the Austin, Texas area.

An unusual amount were all posted in the past four days, all of them have these unknown company names with no logo to them and they all send the user over to LinkedIn when they click apply.

What would be the point of this?

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is necessarily bad...some applications *can* be filled out on LinkedIn directly (the last time I did that was about 4-5 years ago though).  Are they sending you to LinkedIn *then* some other site to fill an application out, or are they just going straight to LinkedIn?

Comment: @Makoto, they are just going over to LinkedIn, but they are ALL doing it, all the ones that just happen to be posted around the same timeframe and just happen to belong to obscure tech companies that just happen to all not have a logo. So none of the IBMs, etcetera, are doing it, but then those are also not following the same pattern of being posted at the same time with no logos to them. It's weird.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The jobs you found are part of a test we’re running with LinkedIn to syndicate job listings.

One of the biggest pain points we’ve heard time and time again is that we don’t have enough jobs & companies listed on Stack Overflow. Growing the job board is one of our main objectives in 2019 and we’re exploring several solutions including syndicating jobs from partners in the space. Syndication is a relatively quick way to provide a lot more jobs in places we historically haven’t had many opportunities.

As we ramp up on job volume, one of the key things we’re paying attention to is job quality. We want to make sure we’re able to consistently identify high-quality listings and successfully filter out irrelevant and fake listings. For this particular test, the listings are curated by LinkedIn, spot-checked on our end, and filtered by what we can reliably target (i.e. based on our algorithms, we’re reasonably confident that it’s a technical role).

We’re currently looking at how we can enable users to give us more feedback on job listings, beyond just flagging SPAM or dismissing listings, so that we can continue to refine our matching algorithms and filtering tools. This is something we expect to continue iterating on through the coming months.

Currently, the application experience for syndicated listings involves redirecting users to the partner’s site (in this case, LinkedIn) to complete the application. If these tests with syndication prove to be successful, we then intend to look into streamlining the application experience itself.

For now, we’re continuing to run tests and gathering feedback & data so that we can decide if this is worth pursuing further and optimizing.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know what is going on. As a member of Stack Overflow, I can say that LinkedIn is a platform that can be gamed as my family personally knows someone who have provided totally bogus credentials and work history, whereas in Stack Overflow, you either know your craft or you don't and the community votes tell us so. I would recommend sticking with further developing the Developer Story and having employers be linked to our Developer Story and data on Stack Overflow. What better way of assessing a candidate than seeing how they contribute on SO?

Comment: Thanks! We do plan on continuing to improve Developer Story, Jobs, and keep growing our list of direct customers. However, that's a much slower process. Hence, we're looking at syndication as a means to complement our strategy. LinkedIn's one of several partners we're speaking with in this space, so hopefully we'll be able to deliver on a set of quality opportunities in your area soon enough :)